# How to correctly compare the current date with the date of the site (just the day) from which the publication is parsed with today's date?

Tags: python, date, string-matching

I need to parse exactly those publications where the publication date coincides with today's date. I only need to match the day. For example, 20 = 20. Here's what I did, but this is not good code:

```
today = date.today()
d2 = today.strftime("%B %d, %Y")
today_day = d2[8] + d2[9]

for el in items:
    title = el.select('.card-stats > div')
    p = title[1].text
    space = p.replace(" ","")
    day = space[1] + space[2]
    if day == today_day:
        data_id = el.get('data-id')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think that the mistake could be in the second part of your code where you throw a variable, day, you didn't define before.

Try:

```
today = date.today()
d2 = today.strftime("%B %d, %Y")
today_day = d2[8] + d2[9]




for el in items:
    title = el.select('.card-stats > div')
    p = title[1].text
    space = p.replace(" ","")
    day = space[1] + space[2]
    
    if today == today_day:
        data_id = el.get('data-id')
```

Comment: I did not understand you. Can you explain please. The code hasn't changed. + I also need to change it so that the code works all the time, and with my code the code has to be constantly changed, because there are different numbers of letters in each month and numbers in each date.

Comment: ok, could you add sample code of input and desired output?

Comment: For example when i print the date, there "January 13", i need to take from that  only "13", so i take d2[8] + d2[9]. But in February "February 15" i need to rewrite the code and write d2[9] + d2[10]. When the date is one digit, like "6" in "February 6", i need to take only d2[9]. I do not want rewrite the code again and again every month. How make it easier?